# "index not backed by a repository" error from libgit2 when writing tree from index for 'pull' commit

Tags: rust, libgit2

When I do `index.write_tree())` (`index` is an `Index` resulting from a merge using `merge_commits`), I get an error "Failed to write tree. the index file is not backed up by an existing repository". I have an existing repository. [It was bare in the original version of this post, but I have changed it to non-bare, and it is still not working.]  What am I doing wrong?

More generally, I am trying to implement `git pull` (a fetch then a merge). In the catch-up case, I understand that after the fetch and the merge, I need to write out a commit. That is what I am trying to do. How do I do that?

Basically, my code is

```rust
 let index = repo.merge_commits(&our_commit, &their_commit, Some(&MergeOptions::new()))?;
 if !index.has_conflicts() {
   let new_tree_oid = index.write_tree()?; // error occurs here
   let new_tree = repo.find_tree(new_tree_oid)?;
   //...
 }
```

This is using the rust `git2` crate, which wraps the `libgit2` library.

Comment: Is there a problem with this question? No one has commented on it at all yet.

Comment: No problem with the question, but the error is quite specific so not many people would be able to answer. You may have better chances contacting liggit2 and libgit-rs communities directly, for example through their github pages.

Comment: @IlyaPopov thanks. The libgit2 site says try stack overflow, but they also have a slack channel, so I've tried that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an *in-memory* index, you don't have *the repository's index*.  This is the distinction that is preventing you from writing it.

You have a few options for dealing with an in-memory index:

1. You can convert it to a tree (and then you could create a commit that uses that tree), using [`git_index_write_tree_to`](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/index/git_index_write_tree_to).  The `write_tree_to` function will let you specify the repository that you want to write to.
2. You can *make* it the repository's index, using [`git_repository_set_index`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/include/git2/sys/repository.h#L120-L134).

Though I would question why you're using `git_merge_commits` instead of just **`git_merge`**, which should take care of all of this for you, including dealing with conflicts.  If you're truly doing a `git pull` emulation, then you'll need to cope with that.